# How to switch in and out of root in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, sudo

So I'm aware that I can run

```
$ sudo script
```

to run a script as the root user.

In this script I NEED to run some commands as root to delete certain directories but I CANNOT run some other commands as root (bower commands that throw errors if run as root)

Right now I have a working script which uses sudo -u to escape root but it is really gross:

```
sudo rm -rf ./node_modules ./bower_components

sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install

sudo -u user bower cache clean
sudo -u user bower install
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

edit in response to  @Etan Reisner's comment

if i change the script to

```
sudo rm -rf ./node_modules ./bower_components

sudo npm cache clean

sudo npm install

bower cache clean
bower install
```

and then run the script without sudo it fails with error

```
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo
```

I don't understand why but having any sudo commands in the script seems to run the bower commands as root.

Comment: Is that script running as root? If it is why have `sudo` on those first three lines? Why does root need to be used to do the npm commands for the current user?

Comment: Are the errors permission related errors?

Comment: You can run the script using sudo rather than using sudo for every command.

Comment: @Etan would like you to remove all sudo's on the root commands and leave sudo in the bower lines (when the script is run as root). Does that work?

Comment: Are you running `sudo script` as you said you were at one point when that error happens? And yes, my point was the opposite if your script is being run as root normally (not that you should be doing that).

Answer (score 1):

Don't run your script with `sudo`.  Run the command lines you need to be root for with `sudo` and then run the lines that you want to be another user without prepending `sudo`.

Better yet, put the root-requiring lines into a second "outer" script and call that script with `sudo` from the "inner" script you run as your non-root user.  And make sure there's **nothing** in that script that doesn't need to run as root.

You might even want to check that you're not root in the beginning of the "outer" or "calling" script and that you are root in the beginning of the "inner" or "called" one.  Spit out an error message and return an error code if those conditions fail.

Comment: if I run a single line as sudo all lines after it were being called as root unless i specified a user with -u

I realize i dont need the other sudos though in that case and I could just call the script as sudo

Comment: @Andrew No, that's not how `sudo` works. It only affects the command you give it specifically.

Comment: I'll try again and see if I interpreted it wrong. I was also surprised by that but it seemed to be happening.